# How to search repeated positions?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, filtering

I am developing a simple game in Haskell. It's a board game, where Pieces are organized on a "board" by coordinates.

```
type Piece = (PType, Orientation,Coordinates)
type PType = Char
type Orientation = String
type Coordinates = (Int,Int)
```

Ok so i read how the board is now from a XML file, and i get a new piece. I want to know what possible plays are possible for that piece in that board.

I look to the first piece, and i see if there are pieces around it. For example imagine a Piece with the coordinates (0,0). If there where other Pieces in the coordinates (1,0),(-1,0),(0,1) and (0,-1) it wouldn't produce any possible play for that new piece that i wanna put in the board, because there are not empty spaces around it. So i have functions that make all possible plays around all pieces in the board.

But i have a problem. So for example, i can have a Piece A in coordinates (0,0) and a Piece B in coordinates (2,0), and after i run all possible plays it will give me a list of possible plays ignoring the plays of each other. Since (1,0) is empty it will diferent plays for that position.

Imagine this list on my output of the possible plays for the example above, for a new piece C. All possible plays would be

```
[
(C,North,(3,0)),
(C,North,(-1,0)),

(C,North,(1,0)),
(C,South,(1,0)),
(C,North,(1,0)),
(C,East,(1,0))
]
```

So as you can see there are multiple plays for the coordinate (1,0). I only want the ones that repeat themselvs. I want to make some kind of filter, that first, only looks to the pieces that repeat the same coordinates of this list of possible plays, and then only takes the pieces that have the same PType and Orientation. So the output for the above list would be

```
[
(C,North,(3,0)),
(C,North,(-1,0)),

(C,North,(1,0)),
]
```

Can someone help with my problem? My atempts on doing this allways get me the same plays lol

Comment: Do you really want all possible moves?  Without a limiting size to the board, there would be infinite possible moves.  Also, if you can generate the first list (with 6 elements), you could use the `nubBy` function from Data.List to filter by the third part of that tuple.  I'd suggest pairing it with `Data.Function.on` as `nubBy (on (==) (\(_, _, c) -> c))`, which will give you a function that compares only the third element of the tuple.

Comment: The moves can only be side by side with an existing piece. The list could be infinite but it's itself limited by the number of pieces on the board. So it there are 1 piece there is a max of 4 possible plays. 2 pieces max 8 possible plays, etc etc. We can only move on +x -x +y and -y. In the example above the problem is that for piece A on (0,0) there are possible plays on the +x that are not combatible with possible plays on Piece B (2,0). That way i need to filter all the possible plays that have the same coordinates and only represent the ones that repeat the same PType and Orientation.

Comment: I'm trying to understand better what makes a move legal or illegal.  What determines the direction when placing a new piece?  Say for example there was only 1 piece on the board `('A', North, (0,0)`.  What are the possible moves for a new piece?  Would there be any difference if piece A was facing a different direction?  Now repeat this example with 2 pieces on the board.  If you need more room than the comment box allows I would suggest editing your question and adding a new section with the information.

Comment: I have a lot of simple functions for that because there are diferent directions, but i will explain just for one side. The others are the same. Let's figure out for -x side (the left). I have the list of all pieces on the board from the xml. Then i use a function that takes one piece, and sees if there is any piece with the coordinates (x-1,y) in it. It returns a bool. Lets call it MinusX. I have a central function that filters all pieces that are clear on left, and then apply another function that figures out what's the possible plays for each one. I do that for 4 sides... To be continued

Comment: So if i apply this proceadure in the example above, the MinusX function would give true for B and the PlusX would give True for Piece A. So it produces the possible plays for both. So the problem is that it doesn't take in consideration the fact that it maybe other pieces producing possible plays for the same coordinates.

Comment: I would produce all possible plays for each piece, then sort and group them according to coordinates.  That would tell you which possible moves have duplicates, and if you have 4 possible moves for a single coordinate, you know that spot is completely surrounded.  Would that tell you enough information to make a decision?  If need be, you could create a new type that represents a possible move and records the PType of the piece it is being played on, but at that point I would suggest refactoring to use record types instead of tuples, it'll make things easier.

Comment: But i already do that bheklilr. My list puts all possible moves for all board and for all 4 positions. All of them. The example above it's not a real output, it's an example. The problem i have is, that the possible play for a piece can be in the same coordinates as other piece. If that happens, i can only put the pieces that repeat in both. That's what i need to filter. There is not any problem behind. I only want to do what i said above. And i don't need to know if a possible play is sorrounded. I need to remove the ones that have the same coordinates, but don't repeat.